# Automatic Xero refresh token update in Azure data factory

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-data-factory, refresh-token, xero-api, xero

I use the Xero connector to extract data from xero API in Azure data factory. I use OAuth 2.0 config. The connection is successful but my refresh token expires every 30 minutes. Is there a way to automate the refresh token update?

I realized that the below mentioned link was useful. But can someone elaborate on how to setup the access tokens?
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/112731/xero-azure-data-factory-connector-operates-success]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know we need to generate refresh token after every 30 min s as earlier got expired to generate it and store it you need to follow steps like below:

> [image]

- You get an initial refresh token by requesting the offline_access scope during the user authorization. store this token in key vault manually.
- With first web activity get that refresh toke from key vault.
- Now with the set variable store the refresh token as string.
- Using that refresh token, you can generate the new refresh token with the another web activity and below values from this [Refreshing access and refresh tokens](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/auth-flow/#refreshing-access-and-refresh-tokens)

```
POST 
https://identity.xero.com/connect/token

#header
authorization: "Basic " + base64encode(client_id + ":" + client_secret)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

#body
grant_type=refresh_token
&refresh_token=xxxxxx
```

- Now store the new and original refresh token to the key vault and use the new in copy activity.

Comment: Thankyou for this response. this is very useful. I had one quick question. Should we keep running this pipeline every half hour? Is there a way to get refresh token with the authorization code. Thant way we can run it only before we run the other actual pipeline?

Comment: You can use execute pipeline activity to run the pipeline before main pipeline