# Xero Azure Connector: how to set up the pipeline to refresh the token

Tags: azure, xero-api

I have followed the answer provided by Pratik Lad to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77309402/automatic-xero-refresh-token-update-in-azure-data-factory) and now I am stuck in the step "GetBearerToken".

For the authorization header, I tried to create the value string using dynamic content:

`@concat('Basic ', 'base64encode(', variables('Clientid'),' + ', variables('APISecret'),')')`

However, I am getting invalid client as the error message.

Would anyone know how to fix it? I am retrieving both client id and client secret from Azure Vault.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Xero Azure Connector: how to set up the pipeline to refresh the token

The `base64encode('Clientid':'APISecret')` expression means it will need `('Clientid':'APISecret')` value in base64 format.

For authorization header you need to specify value like below:

```json
Basic @{base64(concat(variables('Clientid'), ':', variables('APISecret')))}
```

So, it will concat and convert `Clientid:APISecret` to the base64 format.

For more understanding refer [this](https://martinschoombee.com/2022/03/08/working-with-oauth-2-0-apis-in-azure-data-factory-refreshing-tokens/) Document by Martin.

Comment: Thanks, Pratik Lad. That solved my problem!