# Update a Secret in Azure Vault via Azure Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, xero-api

I have been following the steps outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77309402/automatic-xero-refresh-token-update-in-azure-data-factory) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78073511/xero-azure-connector-how-to-set-up-the-pipeline-to-refresh-the-token) to connect Xero to Azure Data Factory. I am unable to update the refresh token and the access token in my vault.

I have set up my web activity as it appears in the image below

[ADF Web activity settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo0rE.png)

And here is the body:

{“value”:”@{activity('GetBearerToken').output.access_token}”}

However, the activity is failing with the following message:

Error details
Save New Xero Access Token
Error code

2108

Failure type User configuration issue
Details
{"error":{"code":"MethodNotAllowed","message":"HTTP POST not allowed"}}
Activity ID
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Are you trying to update the secret value in your own Azure Key Vault?

Comment: Correct, Albert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Update a Secret in Azure Vault via Azure Data Factory Pipeline use **`Put`** method.

```json
URL - https://myvault.vault.azure.net//secrets/crpsecret?api-version=7.4
Method - PUT
Body - @concat('{"value":"',variables('var2'),'"}')
**@concat('{"value":"',activity('GetBearerToken').output.access_token,'"}')**In your case
Authentication - System Assigned Managed Identity
Resource - https://vault.azure.net
```

[image]

Make sure your ADF managed identity have set permissions on secret.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Pratik Lad. I have updated the body field. Unfortunately, it is still not working. My organisation is using role based access control as opposed to access policies. I have given my data factory the role of Key Vault Secrets Officer, but that did not work. I am testing other roles atm as I was able to perform GET requests and read from the vault in previous steps of this pipeline.

Comment: Thanks again, Pratik Lad. I was using the wrong method :( It is working like a charm now